# How can I properly escape a string to be passed to a shell with a command argument

Tags: shell, command-line, quoting

How can I properly escape arbitrary commands?

---

For example:

```
sudo -u chris sh -c 'echo "\"leftright\""'
```

The above echos:

```
"leftright"
```

How would I echo out:

```
"left'right"
```

I've tried the following which I would expect to work but does not:

```
sudo -u chris sh -c 'echo "\"left\'right\""'
```

I can't quite get my head round how it is parsed.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo -u chris sh -c 'echo "\"left'\''right\""'`

Comment: Can you explain this? What other characters do I need to potentially escape to allow any arbitrary commands?

Comment: It's basically how you handle the opening & the closing quote.  For your above example you could also write it as : `sh -c 'echo \"left"'\''"right\"'`. Check [this](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings) for reference. Also check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings) for a good explanation by liori

Answer (score 0):

```
 sh -c 'echo "\"left'"'"'right\""'
```

OR

```
 sh -c 'echo "\"left'\''right\""'
```

will work.

Either of the above will pass

```
 echo "\"left'right\""
```

after `-c`.

When you're inside a single quoted string there is no escaping other than closing that string.

To pass a single quote, you can either use

```
 "'"
```

or

```
 \'
```

.

The shell will concatenate adjacent arguments that don't have an input field separator (usually space) in between.